# How to send deauth packets on Windows (manually or with software)?

Tags: windows, wifi, wireless, deauth-attack

first of all I know how deauth packets work basically. But since my wifi adapter refuses to work on my virtual Kali, I want to use my host machine (Windows 10). So I have NPcap and Wireshark and I can go to monitor mode, change channels and sniff packets on Wireshark. But I can't find any way to send deauth packets on Windows. I have aircrack-ng for Windows downloaded but it just doesn't accept my wi-fi adapter (I use "Wi-Fi" as interface name which is same as netsh show all name so it should be correct) it just sais no interface or not supported or smth like that. And since I can't find any other software or script to send deauth packets, I wanted to do it manually with CMD. I would love to know how can I do that, or if you can tell me if there is a software/program for Windows which sends deauth packets.

Comment: `aireplay-ng` also works on Windows. Also, you can just install Kali on a USB stick and boot from there.

Comment: @MechMK1 Yes, but as I said, it doesn't accept my interface which should be accepted so I'm looking for alternative ways. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't accept my interface"?

Comment: @MechMK1 I have solved the issue with Kali Linux so I can use my adapter with it atm. Thank you for your comments anyway.

Comment: @user163495 aireplay-ng works on Windows with some adapters, but not with all its options. For example is not able to perform a deauth attacks. It's a limitation of the Windows drivers.